# how to compare 3 variables (equalsIgnoreCase) extracted from web services?

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I spent a few days trying to discover volleyball and finally I managed to find ways to use Method.POST. I am using equalsIgnoreCase to create a login. My web services returns a string with 3 parameters.

**State
 - data
 - message**

```
 {"state":"success","data":{"nombre":"user1","email":"user1@gmail.com","cod_user":"8"},"message":"The session was started correctly!"}
```

I see several examples, it only work with one parameter like for example "success"

```
    private void login() {

    if (!validate()) return;

    progress = new ProgressDialog(this);
    progress.setMessage("Starting...");
    progress.show();
    String url = Connection.URL_WEB_SERVICE +"login.php";

    stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            User userParcelable = new User();;
            Log.i("ANSWER JSON: ",""+response);
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                if(jsonObject.names().get(0).equals("success")){

                    email.setText("");
                    password.setText("");

                    userParcelable.setId(jsonObject.getJSONArray("user").getJSONObject(0).getInt("code"));
                    userParcelable.setEmail(jsonObject.getJSONArray("user").getJSONObject(0).getString("email"));
                    userParcelable.setName(jsonObject.getJSONArray("user").getJSONObject(0).getString("name"));

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),jsonObject.getString("success"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    progreso.dismiss();

                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("DATA_USER",userParcelable);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),jsonObject.getString("error"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.i("RESPUESTA JSON: ",""+jsonObject.getString("error"));
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

I hope you orient me a little  thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you just want to check that the presence of parameter in your json object response then you can use [`has`](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#has(java.lang.String)) method which will returns `true` only if the attribute is present in the object, like

```
// && mean every condition should be true
if(jsonObject.has("success") && jsonObject.has("data") && 
      jsonObject.has("message") ){
```

There are more issue here

```
userParcelable.setId(jsonObject.getJSONArray("user").getJSONObject(0).getInt("code"));
```

You have no jsonarray in your code so the above code will produce a crash so use this

```
userParcelable.setId(jsonObject.getJSONObject("data").optLong("cod_user"));
userParcelable.setEmail(jsonObject.getJSONObject("data").optString("email"));
userParcelable.setName(jsonObject.getJSONObject("data").optString("name"));
```

and use `optLong` because code contains a string plus the key is `cod_user` not `code`